# AWS textract to extract pdf data in key value pairs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ocr, amazon-textract

I want to extract data from the below pdf in key-value pairs using aws s3 bucket and textract in python django[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpE3t.jpg)

Here is my current python code and output

```
def extract_data_from_pdf(request):
    if "file" not in request.FILES:
        return Response({"error": "No file found."}, status=400)

    file_obj = request.FILES["file"]
    filename = file_obj.name

    s3_client.upload_fileobj(file_obj, "bucket-name", filename)

    response = textract_client.analyze_document(
        Document={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": "bucket-name",
                "Name": filename,
            }
        },
        FeatureTypes=["FORMS"],
    )
    extracted_data = []
    for item in response["Blocks"]:
        if item["BlockType"] == "KEY_VALUE_SET":
            key = ""
            value = ""
            for entity in item["EntityTypes"]:
                if entity == "KEY":
                    key_id = item["Relationships"][0]["Ids"][0]
                    key_block = next(
                        (
                            block
                            for block in response["Blocks"]
                            if block["Id"] == key_id
                        ),
                        None,
                    )
                    if key_block and "Text" in key_block:
                        key = key_block["Text"]
                elif entity == "VALUE":
                    value_ids = item["Relationships"][0]["Ids"]
                    if len(value_ids) >= 2:
                        value_id = value_ids[1]
                        value_block = next(
                            (
                                block
                                for block in response["Blocks"]
                                if block["Id"] == value_id
                            ),
                            None,
                        )
                        if value_block and "Text" in value_block:
                            value = value_block["Text"]

            extracted_data.append({"key": key, "value": value})

    return Response(extracted_data)
```

Here is the output for the code

[
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": "Fatima"
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": "Years(F)"
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": "To"
},
{
"key": "",
"value": ""
},
{
"key": "",
"value": "Digital"
}
]

I am new to OCR and Text Detection so please ignore my mistakes
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to interact with Amazon Textract in Python is to use the `amazon-textract-textractor` package.

For example for your use-case it would look like this:

```py
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document = extractor.analyze_document(
    file_source="./QpE3t.jpg",
    features=TextractFeatures.FORMS
)
```

You can visualize the output:

```
document.visualize()
```

[image]
Get the key value pairs like this:

```py
document.key_values
```

```
[UHID No : 43908699,
 Name : Kaneez Fatima,
 Age : 55 Years(F),
 EmployeeID : 5062321,
 Plan Period : 12/01/2023 To 11/01/2024,
 Policy No : 411601/48/2023/1232,
 Organisation : Thryve Digital Health LLP]
```

and if you want them in `key` `value` dict format you can do this:

```py
[{'key':str(kv.key), 'value':str(kv.value)} for kv in document.key_values]
```

```
[{'key': 'UHID No', 'value': '43908699'},
 {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Kaneez Fatima'},
 {'key': 'Age', 'value': '55 Years(F)'},
 {'key': 'EmployeeID', 'value': '5062321'},
 {'key': 'Plan Period', 'value': '12/01/2023 To 11/01/2024'},
 {'key': 'Policy No', 'value': '411601/48/2023/1232'},
 {'key': 'Organisation', 'value': 'Thryve Digital Health LLP'}]
```